# communicating with a device in linux through a buffer

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to figure out how to allocate a contiguous memory buffer in physical memory and get its physical address. I've read a number of posts on this on SO but none of them seem to be working.

As far as I understand I have to create a kernel module for this. I'm also reading the Linux Device Drivers, 3rd edition. It has a lot of useful information but so far I haven't found what I'm looking for. I'm not new to linux but I've never worked on a kernel and driver level.

So far I've tried the following

```
virtAddr = kmalloc(mysize, GFP_KERNEL);
physAddr = virt_to_phys(virtAddr);
printk("virtAddr = %x, physAddr = %x\n", virtAddr, physAddr);
kfree(virtAddr);
```

And the following:

```
virtAddr = dma_alloc_coherent(NULL, mysize, &mydma_handle, GFP_KERNEL);
physAddr = virt_to_phys(virtAddr);
physAddr = virt_to_phys(virtAddr);
printk("virtAddr = %x, physAddr = %x\n", virtAddr, physAddr);
dma_free_coherent(NULL, mysize, virtAddr, dma_handle);
```

When I look at the `dmesg` log I see that in both cases virtAddr and physAddr have the same values, i.e for case one it would would look like (the value is not exact, it was just chosen to demonstrate an point)

```
virtAddr = d00abe, physAddr = d00abe
```

and for case 2 it the output would look like (the value is not exact, it was just chosen to demonstrate an point)

```
virtAddr = ac435f, physAddr = ac435f
```

I'm running this code on a regular PC with an Intel processor so I seriously have doubts that virtual and physical addresses could have the same value. Clearly I misunderstood something, so if someone could educate me on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What class of device is it?  Is there not already a driver for it?

Comment: @wallyk There is no driver for it. Another team will develop it much later. My job is to test the device by communicating with it. To do this I need a buffer, the physical address of a buffer and a virtual address of a buffer. Why? It is a long story. The device itself doesn't even exist yet. I'm sure developers encounter this problem on a regular basis, I'm just surprised that I haven't found an answer that works.

Comment: The usual Linux driver development path is to find an existing driver which closely resembles the device and see if it can be made to work:  that is, extended for the new device.  If not, then copy and adapt as required.   You haven't given enough information for me to do the search for an existing driver for you.

Comment: @wallyk What information do you need?